# Как определенному значению присвоить текст

Tags: c++

Зашел в тупик с программой, вот её упрощенный вариант:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;
int s1, s2, s3;

int main()
{
    setlocale (LC_ALL, "Russian");
    cout << "Введите значение: " << endl;
    cout << "Тряпка: ";
    cin >> s1;
    cout << "Швабра: ";
    cin >> s2;
    cout << "Метла: ";
    cin >> s3;
    int massive[3];
    massive[1] = s1;
    massive[2] = s2;
    massive[3] = s3;
    int max = massive[1];
    for (int k = 1; k <= 3; k++)
    {
        if (max < massive[k]) max = massive[k];
    }
    cout << "Максимальное значение: " << max;
    getch();
    return 0;

}
```

Например, присвоили значение каждой переменой:

`Тряпка: 5`

`Швабра: 8`

`Метла: 1`

Оно выдаст максимальное значение - `8`.

Суть в том, что нужно, чтобы выводило не число `8`, а слово `Швабра`. Как это сделать? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Индексы с нуля, то есть от 0 до 2, если размер 3.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, так

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int values[3];
    const char* names[3];

    names[0] = "Тряпка";
    names[1] = "Швабра";
    names[2] = "Метла";

    setlocale (LC_ALL, "Russian");
    cout << "Введите значение: " << endl;
    cout << names[0] << ": ";
    cin >> values[0];
    cout << names[1] << ": ";
    cin >> values[1];
    cout << names[2] << ": ";
    cin >> values[2];

    int max = 0;
    for (int k=0; k<3; ++k)
    {
        if (values[max] < values[k]) max = k;
    }
    cout << "Максимальное значение: " << names[max];
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Задача очень просто решается с помощью `std::map`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    std::map<int, string> utensils;
    int tmpValue = 0;
    cout << "Введите значение: " << endl;
    cout << "Тряпка: ";
    cin >> tmpValue;
    utensils.emplace(tmpValue, "Тряпка");
    cout << "Швабра: ";
    cin >> tmpValue;
    utensils.emplace(tmpValue, "Швабра");
    cout << "Метла: ";
    cin >> tmpValue;
    utensils.emplace(tmpValue, "Метла");
    cout << "Максимальное значение: " << utensils.rbegin()->second << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Как Вы можете видеть, для задачи ассоциации некоторого значения со строкой, мы используем ассоциативную структуру данных, которая, к тому же, всегда поддерживается в отсортированном состоянии.

Comment: Только вот для задачи TC (и кучи подобных) это называется -- "из пушки по воробьям" (представляете, сколько ресурсов уходит на RB-tree, которым обычно реализуют map?)

Comment: @avp, мы не знаем задачи автора. Нам он показал лишь *упрощённый* вариант. Кроме того, т.к. мы имеем тег *C++*, то задача должна решаться в духе *C++*, а это значит использовать стандартные средства, коим и является `std::map`. Без оглядки на то, что в какой-то задаче он может быть не очень эффективным. Отказ от его использования должен сопровождаться доказательством его неэффективности.

Comment: IMHO Вы не совсем правы. Последовательное применение такого подхода (точнее такого понимания крестового духа) приводит к появлению массы ресурсоемкого (и часто глючного) софта (что, собственно, мы и наблюдаем в последние лет 20).

Comment: А в чём тогда плюсовость? Использование `cout/cin/string` или что у файла расширение `cpp`? Для данной задачи **любое** проявление `++` очевидно избыточно. Но тогда непонятно на чём учиться, если не на крохотных примерах?

Comment: @Abyx, `то не надо писать using namespace std;`, `return 0;`. `И не надо использовать std::string чтобы хранить строковые литералы` - глупости. `если есть rbegin` - согласен, поправил.

Comment: @Abyx, контейнер никто не сортирует, это обычное свойство r/b tree. В общем, мимо кассы.

Comment: @klopp, не совсем понял Ваш комментарий.Как я уже говорил выше, задача не ясна, т.к. приведен лишь упрощённый вариант.

Comment: Я отвечал @avp - про "применение подхода". В этом случае вообще можно выкинуть нафиг тег `c++` :) Ибо для **подавляющего** большинства задач в местных вопросах `c++` вообще не нужен.

Comment: @Abyx,  конечно. Но всё это было бы сложнее написать. Пример с `std::map` короче. А в данном случае, на мой взгляд, краткость превалирует над производительностью. Обратное справедливо для задачи, где производительность важна.

Comment: Отдельный +1 за `utensils`.

Comment: Какой-то еще более странный вариант чем предыдущий. А если ТСу надо будет 100 строк сопоставить с числами, он так и будет копипастить по 3 строчки на каждое слово? Зачем для поиска максимума нужен map это конечно совсем за гранью здравого смысла. Отвратительный и бессмысленный вариант.

Comment: @outcast, если надо будет 100 строк, то надо будет включить голову и дописать общий код. `std::map` используется не для того, чтобы найти максимальный элемент, а потому, что он реализует модель словаря, т.е. ассоциативного массива. Получение максимального элемента лишь приятный бонус.

Comment: Так почему бы сразу голову не включать и не написать нормально, а не такие ужасы? И чего ты решил что тут кому-то нужна модель словаря, каков смысл решать не ту задачу что поставлена а еще какую-то выдуманную другую?

Comment: @outcast, сбавьте обороты, хамить друзьям своим на завалинке будете. Задача стоит в ассоциации числового значения со строкой. Словарь это другое название *ассоциативного массива*. Я ничего не выдумывал, я решал исходную задачу теми средствами, которые я считаю приемлемыми. Не нравится? Ставьте минус и пишите свой ответ. Мне Ваше мнение до лампочки.

Comment: Так смысл писать, откровенно плохой код, в ответе человеку который плохо разбирается в вопросе. Неужели сделать тоже самое с использованием цикла вместо копипасты представляет такую сложность для человека который знает что такое  std::map. P.S. Если бы ТС мог "включить голову" он бы не задавал этот вопрос.

Comment: @outcast, я буду откровенен, я не уделил этому ответу достаточно времени и написал то, что первым пришло в голову. Я просто взял исходный текст и вставил в него `std::map`. Да, я согласен, что реализация, мягко говоря, не очень, но как идея - вполне подходит. Чтобы запихнуть это в цикл пришлось бы вводить ещё один массив, который бы содержал наименования, я решил этого не делать. В результате получился такой противоречивый ответ. Но, как мы видим, автор принял другой ответ как правильный и этого ему достаточно.

Answer (score 1):

Каноничное решение на С++ это

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <clocale>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

  std::vector<const char*> names = {"Тряпка", "Швабра", "Метла"};
  std::vector<int> values(names.size());

  std::cout << "Введите значения:\n";
  for (unsigned i = 0; i != names.size(); ++i) {
    std::cout << names[i] << ": ";
    std::cin >> values[i];
  }

  int index = std::max_element(values.begin(), values.end()) - values.begin();
  std::cout << "Максимальное значение: " << names[index] << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Если на C++, то наверное `std::string`?

Comment: Преждевременная оптимизация, не? В отсутствие жёстких проблем с производительностью нужно руководствоваться семантикой.

Comment: Тем не менее, идиоматичная строка в C++ — это именно `std::string`. То, что литерал не даёт идиоматичную строку — тяжёлое наследие задекларированной совместимости с C на уровне исходного кода. Отказ от использования _the_ строки в C++ обычно продиктован (обычно сомнительными) соображениями эффективности. Других причин я не встречал.

Comment: Насчёт пессимизации вы, думаю, шутите. Ручное управление памятью, прилагающееся бесплатно к C-style-строкам — гораздо более серьёзная проблема. То, что код не пользуется ничем в строках, тем не менее не означает, что можно отказываться от правильных строк. Малейшее усложнение программы выльется в проблемы.

Comment: "Каноничное решение на С++", и вдруг вместо итераторов unsigned int и цикл до .size() ? И совершенно непонятно зачем константный массив константных строк пихать в вектор. И зачем из итератора, после нахождения максимума, делать номер, почему бы просто не разыменовать?